# Adding a link messes up icons

Tags: html, css

So this is what I currently [have](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FHElB). When I do

`<a href="#"></a>`

the icons shift up and they get messed up. As you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBgdy/). The blue icon is the one that I want to be linked, but it's out of place. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a direct child CSS relationship with this code:

```
.fs1 > span {
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

Change it to include all children:

```
.fs1 span {
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

### [Revised CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyvHp/)

---

---

The `>` operator in CSS signifies a **direct child** relationship, as such:

```
<div>
   <a class="one"></a>
   <span>
       <a class="two"></a>
   </span>
</div>
```

`a.one` can be targeted with `div > a`, however, since there is a span inbetween the div and `a.two`, `div > a` **does not** target `a.two`.

To target `a.two` and `a.one`, you would change it to `div a`, which applies to all a tags found inside of a div tag.

Answer (score 0):

your code is broken, you forgot to close the `<a>` opening tag its missing its `>`

and remove the `>` from the `fs1 > span`  make it just `fs1 span`

Answer (score -1):

```
<a></a>
```

css

```
a:hover, a:active:, a:visited, a:focus, a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

all line:

```
<div>
<a><span></span><span></span></a>
<a><span></span><span></span></a>
<a><span></span><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd implement this. Maybe a clear and quick answer would help. Just posting code wont help instantly most of the time

Comment: This doesn't even begin to answer his question or address the problem.